# Multiple input AND/OR gate evaluation

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

In MPC, AND and XOR gates are two mostly used gates. However, most of the solutions (Garbled Circuit or Boolean Secret Sharing) considered these gates having 2 input wires and 1 output wire.

I am curious on how the case of multiple input wires can be handled. Specially, suppose there are 3 parties and they want to compute the function $f(a,b,c)=a\wedge b\wedge c$, where $a,b,c$ belong to three paries A,B,C, respectively. (There are even more parties, like 100, 1000 or more)

I only know that the BMR (a generalization of Garbled Circuit can be used). Is there an analog in Boolean Secret Sharing world that can compute this with one round of computation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about >2 parties to the entire computation, or >2 inputs to a single gate? The two questions are orthogonal. The answer to >2 inputs to a gate is that every computation can be written as a circuit of 2-input gates.

Comment: Hi, @Mikero, I was asking about more than 2 parties, where each party hold one input.